# Flask Unique Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a blog where a user can make posts. And I want the title of the post be unique. But when I try to make a post and the post already exists returns an error. But when I write a try it still returns.

```
@app.route('/makepost/',methods=['POST','GET'])
@limiter.limit('10 per 10 minutes',cost=ifonly)
def makepost():
    try:
        allposts = Post.query.all()
        sear = 1
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/login')
        poster = Users.query.filter_by(name=current_user.name).first()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            title = request.form['title']
            content = request.form['content']
            if len(title) < 5:
                flash("Title must be at least 5")
            if len(title) > 50:
                flash("Title must be 50 characters max")
            if  len(content) < 5:
                flash('Content must be at least 5 letters')
            if len(title) > 5 and len(title) < 50 and len(content) > 5:
                sear = 2
            if sear == 2:
                global post1
                post1 = Post(title=title,content=content,name=current_user.name,author=current_user.id)
                post2 = Post.query.all()    
                db.session.add(post1)
                db.session.commit()
        # error, there already is a user using this bank address or other
        # constraint failed
            if sear != 2:
                    flash('We couldnt make your post')
    except:
        pass
    return render_template('posts.html')



class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text,unique=False,nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),unique=False)
```

Comment: what do you think `except:
        pass` does?

Comment: I changed it with ``flash('Error`)`` but I still get the same error even when I have a try.